# Change video orientation by 90 degrees anticlockwise after recording is done?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-video-player

I am recording a video using front camera in a particular orientation and then i am uploading it to server , to do some open cv analysis to it but the video server receiving is in landscape mode (horizontally align) so it can not do it's analysis properly .

What i want is that before uploading the video i some how can change it's orientation by by 90 degrees anticlockwise so that analysis can be done properly ?

Comment: in opencv you can rotate by 90 degrees with tranpose and flip operations. There are answers on StackOverflow

Comment: @Micka yeah i know i can do that but i just want to find out if i can do this through android ..btw thanks :)

Comment: remove tje opencv tag please

Comment: @Micka okay it is done

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself , answering so that if someone find himself in same position hoping it will help

Main point was to understand the difference between
`android.hardware.Camera camera.setDisplayOrientation(degrees1);`  and                  `MediaRecorder mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(degrees2);`

former set the way your camera preview will look when you are recording and latter one will set the way your recorded video will be playback when you will play it after.

So if you want your user to record in one orientation(for eg landscape) and then show it to him in portrait way (and can not do so just by setting **android:orientation** , happens sometimes in pretty specific cases)then this will be helpful .